# Javascript resubmit doesn't work after finding an error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

when I check the box and the script doesn't find any error, I can submit it OK. However, when I don't check the box, an "error" occur and I am not able to click the SEND button again. It stops working (only the error text disappears but I am not redirected to after submit page). What can I do to improve that?

The reason for using **dokoncit!=1** is that there are much more ifs before that. I just didn't want to post it here because it is not necessary. It doesn't work even with this one condition.

```
 $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
  var thisName=$(this).attr('name');
  $('input[name='+thisName+']').each(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.checkbox').css('background-color','rgb(253, 92, 22)');
  });
  $(this).siblings('.checkbox').css('background-color','rgb(0, 0, 0)');
});

$("input[name='pohlavi']").click(function(){
  $('#pohlavi_err').html('');
});


$('#form').submit(function(){
  var dokoncit = 1;

  if (!$("input[name='pohlavi']:checked").val()) {
    $('#pohlavi_err').html('<font color="red">Musíš zadat, jestli jseš kluk nebo holka</font>');
    var dokoncit = 'pohlavi';
  }

if(dokoncit!=1){
  console.log(dokoncit);
  shakeButton('#reg_button');
  return false;
}else{
  return true;
}
});
```

Part of the form:

```
 <form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" id="form">
<label>Muž <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="m" class="graphic_checkbox" '.((getRequest('pohlavi')=='m'||$fb_gender=='male')?'checked="checked"':'').'></label>
        <label>Žena <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="f" class="graphic_checkbox" '.((getRequest('pohlavi')=='f'||$fb_gender=='female')?'checked="checked"':'').'></label>
        <span id="pohlavi_err"></span>
```

THANK YOU for some help!

Comment: Please add the relevant elements to your HTML.

Comment: a demo in jsfiddle would be better